# Custom coverage test runner doesn't create DB

Tags: database, django, unit-testing

I'm using Django to create a Rest application.
I'm currently working on unit testing my application and instead of doing a `coverage source=="." manage.py test myapp --settings="mycustomsettings"` I decided to create a script that can start my tests and run them with a custom conf file and a coverage result.
Here is my tree :

```
|-- apps
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- me_api
|   |-- me_auth
|   |-- me_core
|   |-- me_import
|   `-- me_payment
|-- manage.py
|-- settings.py
|-- settings.pyc
|-- tests
|   |-- coveragerunner.py
|   |-- geodjango.db
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- local_settings.py
|   `-- settings.py
|-- urls.py
`-- urls.pyc
```

I want to test the apps that are in the apps/ folder.
Here is my code (in tests/coveragerunner.py)

```
import os
import sys
from coverage import coverage

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../"))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tests.settings'

def main():
    """
    Run tests and generates a coverage report.
    """
    cov = coverage()
    cov.erase()
    cov.start()

    from django.conf import settings
    from django.test.utils import get_runner

    TestRunner = get_runner(settings)
    test_runner = TestRunner()
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(['me_api'])

    cov.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm using the geodjango.db which is a spatialite db as my default db for tests.
My script takes the settings for django but when I run it, it seems that the database is empty. I doesn't sync the DB on its own.

```
DatabaseError: no such table: me_auth_emailuser
```

Is there a way I can tell django to sync the db before running the tests or maybe did I do something wrong ? Thanks.

PS : When I used the manager.py there was no problem with the DB. (even with the spatialite db and the different settings source)

Comment: Did you make a syncdb before running the test?

Comment: As it uses another database, when I run a syncdb, it syncs the postgresql database and not the spatialite. If I could sync this DB, I would. Or maybe I don't know how to sync another db.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution goes as follows:

1. Set the database engine to sqlite, also for non-tests.
2. Make a syncdb to create a template for the test database.
3. Now the tests should work.
4. Don't forget to set the database engine back to postgesql.

Comment: I think that when the tests are run, the database is created, no ? It asks me if I want to delete the db or cancel the operation.

Comment: To properly create a test database, the test runner needs a "real" database as a template. This must be in the same format (e.g. lighthttpd) as the test database.